# database rows to HTML select

Tags: php

I'm trying to populate my dropdown list with informations of my DB. I Use this code:

```
<select name="teste">
    <?php
    include "conecta.php";
    $sql = sqlsrv_query("select * from carro");
    sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo "<option value=\"teste1\">" . $row['placa'] . "</option>";
    }
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
    ?>
</select>
```

But don't appear any information in my list.
Someone can help me to figure whats wrong in my code?

Comment: Have you got results from your database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not making the query to the database correctly. This is then causing a PHP error and hence not executing the while loop. The line should be:

```
$sql = sqlsrv_query($conn, "select * from carro");
```

or

```
$query = "select * from carro";
$sql = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
```

You might also want to specify that you are wanting the *associative* array from the query response, as you are looking for `$row['placa']`. Like so:

```
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){...}
```

Comment: Hello, I changed what you said and now it is working. Thanks.